# Crash on scene load - java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, crash, floating-point, unity-game-engine

I believe the following error to be some variable somewhere in my many files to be a float used like a int or somthing like that:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float
```

But for the life of me, I cannot find where this happens, debugged everything, and well maybe this info below can allow someone much smarter then myself get to the bottom of it. I am using Unity and the crash happens after everything in the scene is loaded.

Let me know if you need more information.

From the logcat:

```
W/dalvikvm( 3999): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2833)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at com.unity3d.player.PlayerPrefs.GetInt(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3999):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Comment: Can you post more of the error message?

Comment: like whats seen on the phone? becuase thats all i have for the error message, unless there is a log somewhere other then logcat?

Comment: could you send the code that you used?

Comment: i dont know where its happening, i have about 15-20 files that run on this scene, what should i look for in the code

Comment: Does the error happen at any specific point?  load/pause etc?  Currently the only clues you've given us is that it's an int being cast to a float, you're using unity and it's somewhere in the unity prefs.  Have you tried clearing the data for the app and trying it again?

Comment: ok these are all good clues i will go through the unity prefs but where can i find out if something is suppose to be an int.. hmm

Comment: Your hints paid off, I was setting a playerpref incorrectly and after I reset the data for the app like Martyn suggested the problem showed it self quickly thanks everyone, i cant post as a answer until 8 hours so whoever gets it first gets it

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if there's an entry in your user or application preferences that contains a float value, but which Unity expects to be an integer.